# Programmatically triggering a Logic App with Recurrence Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, serverless

I have a Logic App which has a recurrence trigger set to trigger every 1 hour, but currently, we are working on some requirements where we need to trigger the Logic App from our API as well.

So I was wondering if there is a way how we can trigger a Logic App programmatically from our App Service? Or is there any way where I can have 2 triggers for the Logic App - Recurrence and HTTP trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that because the Recurrence Trigger is the Trigger.

What you can do is separate the business logic into it's own Logic App using an HTTP Trigger, then that Logic App can be called from the Recurrence Trigger Logic App or externally.

Comment: I ended up doing this. I wish this feature is added in the future.

Comment: Which answer is correct? … can you actually trigger a Recurrence logic app using the REST API?

Comment: @SteveC The Answer is correct.  The second part is an alternative.

Comment: @Johns-305, I disagree. Your answer says "No, there is no way" which is not accurate. There is a way to "trigger a Logic App programmatically from [an] App Service". I agree that the second part of your answer is an alternative, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the *Recurrence* trigger manually.

Below is an example request outline. You can also find documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggers/run).

> POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[subscription](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%5Bsubscription)
> id]/resourceGroups/[resource group
> name]/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/[logic app
> name]/triggers/[trigger name (e.g.
> Recurrence)]/run?api-version=2016-06-01
>
> Authorization: Bearer [a
> bearer token]
>
> Content-type: application/json

Comment: Which answer is correct? … can you actually trigger a Recurrence logic app using the REST API?